# Optimizing read of a big file

Tags: python, generator

I need to scan a big file(2.2GB) and basically retrieve from each line the first two words.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
"""
A generator, given a file object and an integer N, it will return N lines at a time.
"""
def generate_N_Lines(fileObj, N):
    lines = []
    for i in range(N):
        lines.append(fileObj.readline())
    yield lines

    while lines[0]:
        lines = []
        for j in range(N):
            lines.append(fileObj.readline())
        yield lines
    yield None


def process_pileup(lines, res):
    if not lines:
        return

    for line in lines:
        data = str(line).split('\t')
        res.append([data[0], data[1]])


def scanPileup(pileup_path):
    res = []
    with open(pileup_path) as f:
        for lines in generate_N_Lines(f, 4):
            process_pileup(lines, res)
    print(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scanPileup(path/to/file)
```

Problem is that this takes ages to run - last time I tried to it took more than 5 hours and I just gave up and stopped it.
I couldn't figure out a way to try and diminish the runtime.
How can I optimize my code?

file type: txt
file format [Pileup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pileup_format)
one line for example: `seq1 272 T 24  ,.$.....,,.,.,...,,,.,..^+. <<<+;<<<<<<<<<<<=<;<;7<&`

Comment: Can you show what does your file look like?

Comment: add some meta information, your file type, etc.

Comment: Each line looks in this format
```seq1 272 T 24  ,.$.....,,.,.,...,,,.,..^+. <<<+;<<<<<<<<<<<=<;<;7<&
```
The format is called [Pileup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pileup_format)

Comment: The first two words you mean "seq1" and "272"?

Comment: @AerysS Yeah, indeed

Comment: Have you tried this library? https://pypi.org/project/pysam/

Comment: I haven't, will take a look

Comment: What is the reason for not using a simpler yet at least also efficient code like `for line in open(pileup_path): data = str(line).split('\t')
        res.append([data[0], data[1]])`?

Comment: No reason, I had multiple versions of this code from frustration over this endless file read